# Pattern matching on object.member in Play 2.0 templates

Tags: templates, scala, playframework, pattern-matching, playframework-2.0

According to the [Play 2.0 documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplates), pattern matching can be done in a template like so:

```
@connected match {

  case models.Admin(name) => {
    <span class="admin">Connected as admin (@name)</span>
  }

  case models.User(name) => {
    <span>Connected as @name</span>
  }   
}
```

The text between the brackets after the case expressions is treated as output (e.g. HTML), and this is quite convenient.

However, when attempting to use a match expression that is not a simple variable, such as object.member, like this:

```
@album.year match {
   case Some(y: Int) => { @y }
   case None => { <b>nope</b> }
}
```

it results in a compilation error:
`"')' expected but 'case' found."`

Using `defining` to bind the expression to a simple variable, like this:

```
@defining(album.year) { foo =>
  @foo match {
        case Some(y: Int) => { @y }
        case None => { <b>nope</b> }
      }
  }
```

works, but it seems a bit cumbersome.

Is there a proper way to use this pattern matching feature on expressions that involve an object and a member (e.g. `album.year`)?

Comment: does 
@(album.year match {
   case Some(y: Int) => { @y }
   case None => { <b>nope</b> }
})
or
@(album.year) match {
   case Some(y: Int) => { @y }
   case None => { <b>nope</b> }
}
work?

Comment: No, neither of these work.  The first results in "expected start of definition", and the second results in the same "')' expected..." error as above.

Comment: does @{album.year match { case Some(y: Int) => { @y } case None => { <b>nope</b> } }} work?

Comment: Nope, same outcome ("expected start of definition").

Comment: Thanks for the temporary workaround. It appears to be patched, but not yet released in a stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible (in version 2.0.1), as it is a confirmed bug:

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/46-support-more-complex-match-statement

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
@album.year match {

   case Some(y: Int) => {
     @y 
   }
   case None => { 
     <b>nope</b> 
   }
}
```

See here for an example: https://github.com/bjartek/computer-database-mongo/blob/matchtest/app/views/list.scala.html#L67

It looks like whitespace is very important to get right when doing this in the template

Comment: OK, just tried it with the adjusted whitespace.  It still doesn't work. The difference between your example and mine is that your match expression is a simple identifier (@company) and mine is @object.member.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing this?

```
@album.year.getOrElse("<b>None</b>");
```

Not sure if it is as simple as that, but it should work.  See https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/computer-database/app/views/list.scala.html#L64

Comment: I know that's a possible alternate way to solve the simple example that appears in my question... however, that example was just for demonstrating the problem, i.e. pattern matching in Play is either not working completely, or not working as expected.